# Python strip method

Tags: python

Today in python terminal, I tried

```
a = "serviceCheck_postmaster"
a.strip("serviceCheck_")
```

But instead of getting `"postmaster"`,  I got `"postmast"`.

What could cause this? And how can I get `"postmaster"` as output?

Answer (score 20):

You are misunderstanding what `.strip()` *does*. It removes *any* of the characters found in the string you pass. From the [`str.strip()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

> The *chars* argument is a string specifying the **set** of characters to be removed.

emphasis mine; the word `set` there is crucial.

Because `chars` is treated as a set, `.strip()` will remove all `s`, `e`, `r`, `v`, `i`, `c`, `C`, `h`, `k` and `_` characters from the start and end of your input string. So the `e` and `r` characters from the *end* of your input string were also removed; those characters are part of the set.

To remove a string from the start or end, use slicing instead:

```
if a.startswith('serviceCheck_'):
    a = a[len('serviceCheck_'):]
```

Comment: To clarify this in case it's unclear: Python, when looking at the end of the string, asks "Is `'r'` in the character set `"serviceCheck_"`?" Yes! Delete it! "Is `'e'` in the character set `"serviceCheck_"`?" Yes! Delete it! "Is `'t'` in the character set `"serviceCheck_"`?" No! Stop trimming stuff from the end of this string.

Comment: ok, thank you for clarification, I thought it will strip the whole string. If possible, please suggest me a good tutorial for understanding these things

Comment: @user1960543: I've linked to the documentation for the method; when in doubt, read the documentation. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Why isn't the 's' in 'postmaster' stripped out?

Comment: @ClockSlave: because `p`, `o` and `t` are not in the word `serviceCheck_`. Stripping takes place from the start and end, not the middle.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to Martijn's answer to would to use `str.replace()`

```
>>> a = "serviceCheck_postmaster"
>>> a.replace('serviceCheck_','')
'postmaster'
```

Comment: which in this case works, but in the case of `serviceCheck_postmaster:serviceCheck_foobar` would do the wrong thing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The OP hasn't actually provided enough information for you to be certain that he wants your behaviour and not Harpal's in that case - but you're probably right.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- True, but you could make it do the *right* thing by only replacing the first occurrence (`a.replace('serviceCheck_','',1)`) ... But then it might be doing the wrong thing in the case of `postmaster:serviceCheck_foobar` I suppose ...

Comment: @MarkAmery: Since `.strip()` removes characters only from the start or end, I am presuming that that was the intention.

Answer (score 4):

If you carefully look at the help of the strip function
It says like this:

```
Help on built-in function strip:

strip(...)
    S.strip([chars]) -> string or unicode

    Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing
    whitespace removed.
    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
    If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping
```

It will remove all the leading and trailing character and whitespaces. In your case the character sets are

```
s, e, r, v, i, c, C, h, k and _
```

You can get the postmaster by something like this

```
a = "serviceCheck_postmaster"
print a.split("_")[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also isolate "postmaster" with something like this:

```
a = "serviceCheck_postmaster"
b = a.split("_")[1]             # split on underscore and take second item
```

Comment: I'd use `str.partition()` to split just the once, then. Or at the very least limit the splitting with `a.split('_', 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Strip will take away all the letter you input into its function. So for the reason why the letter ‘e’ and ‘r’ were stripped of postmaster.
Try:
a = “serviceCheck_postmaster”
print(a[13:])